# How to simulate death rate and visualize them as dots disappearing over time

Tags: python, visualization, simulation

So, I just solved an ODE model for a population's death rate using scipy and plotted it in a 2d graph against time. I thought it would be interesting if I can visualize the population as dots disappearing at its death rate defined by the ODE. What are some good Python libraries and GUI that can handle this?

Add. info:

How I solved the ODEs:

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

L = 1500
alpha = 0.25
sigma = 0.75
TS = 1.0
ND = 120
m = 0.24
mu = 0.06
w = 10000
H0 = 45000 #initial number of hive bees
F0 = 15000 #initial number of forager bees
INPUT = (H0, F0)

def death_rates(INP, t):
    Y = np.zeros((2))
    V = INP #V[0] = H, V[1] = F
    Y[0] = ((L*(V[0]+V[1]))/(w+V[0]+V[1])) - V[0]*(alpha - sigma*(V[1]/(V[0]+V[1]))) - mu*V[0]
    Y[1] = V[0]*(alpha - sigma*(V[1]/(V[0]+V[1]))) - m*V[1]
    return Y

t_start = 0.0; t_end = ND; t_inc = TS
t_range = np.arange(t_start, t_end+t_inc, t_inc)
RES = spi.odeint(death_rates, INPUT, t_range)

print RES
pl.subplot(311)
pl.plot(RES[:,0], '-g', label='Hive Bees')
pl.xlabel('Time')
pl.ylabel('Hive Bees')
pl.subplot(312)
pl.plot(RES[:,1], '-r', label='Forager Bees')
pl.xlabel('Time')
pl.ylabel('Forager Bees')
pl.show()
```

which generated the following graph:
[image: 2D plot of the population decline]

Basically, what I want to do is to animate the results as dots (bees) initially at population number N0 continuously disappearing until it plateaus at population N1 in a span of say, 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly works with Python. The "gapminder" example at the end of this link is similar to what you want.

Scroll down to the end.

https://plot.ly/python/animations/

Here is a screen shot - but it is best animated:

[image]

Can't really get you more then this without example data and more details about what you want (I can visualize a few things that match what you described).

Comment: I think a more straightforward example of what I want to do is suppose I have 1000 random dots (the population) on the screen, and they have to continuously disappear until only 20 dots are left in a span of 60 seconds.

Comment: Post some code generating the data, and I would get around to doing a plotly with it. Unless someone beat me to it of course.